# How to tag and send logs to /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, ldap

Im new to linux and logging.  I would like to tag and send certain LDAP data logs from one log file to /var/log/messages.  RHEL 6/7

/opt/oracle/product/dsee7/data/{{certain_instance}}/logs/access

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include distro/version so I can't get advice specific to a particular one, but generally you would use the imfile module for rsyslog.

> This module provides the ability to convert any standard text file into a syslog message. A standard text file is a file consisting of printable characters with lines being delimited by LF.

https://rsyslog-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules/imfile.html

If this sounds good, you will want to look at the rsyslog documentation for your release as the configuration syntax has changed over time. Do not assume that the 'latest' link above will be appropriate for you.

Comment: Im sorry.  Im dealing with RHEL 6/7.  Thanks

Comment: Advice on imfile stands, but you definitely want to look at how modules are loaded/configured for both versions of rsyslog that ship with those two releases.